# Calculating possible combinations with varying sized sets

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not great at mathematics, so I'm not sure what formula I should be looking for.

I want to find the total possible combinations of different sets, where the set sizes vary.

For example: 
I'm making robots with the following parts: HEAD, BODY, ARMS-SET, LEGS-SET.
If there are 6 different HEADs available, 3 different BODIES, 5 different ARMS-SET, and 2 different LEGS-SET, how many possible different robots could I produce?

And what is the formula to find this? Is it just 6*3*5*2?

Comment: It seems that you have done your work systematically, starting at the top and multiplying by the number of choices at each stage working downward.  Since the choices available at each stage are independent of the choices made previously, the answer is the product you showed.  The product is the formula.  Is there something about this you have a question about?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is simple multiplication principle.